# Using an Inline Directive to pass total amount to PayPal Integration

Tags: c#, asp.net, inline, paypal-sandbox, directive

So I have a PayPal integration on my ASP.NET Webforms site but cannot seem to figure out from their online documentation how to pass my own total variable to the integration. My total is stored in a label on the page which calculates on page load

```
<label id="lblHiddenTotal" runat="server" hidden="hidden" name="amount"></label>
```

Would using Inline directives be a good way to pass my variable to the PayPal Express Checkout?and if so how exactly do I let my label equal to the directive? I was also thinking I could use a session variable to pass my variable, which option would be better?

The Js code for the PayPal button is as follows:

```js
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>
     <script>
        paypal.Button.render({
            env: 'sandbox', // sandbox | production
            style: {
                label: 'pay',
                size: 'small', // small | medium | large | responsive
                shape: 'rect',   // pill | rect
                color: 'gold'   // gold | blue | silver | black
            },
            // PayPal Client IDs - replace with your own
            // Create a PayPal app: https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/create
            client: {
                sandbox:    'AWDwdGr-KZK4jJi0WBUZmFowgG6oCtLpNDxtXuiOfAT1UdNUYeSlvoXYkrKW7SRdcYqqjHCo7IcYPmJf',
                production: 'Production ClientID'
            },
            // payment() is called when the button is clicked
            payment: function(data, actions) {
                // Make a call to the REST api to create the payment
                return actions.payment.create({
                    payment: {
                        transactions: [
                            {
                                amount: { total: '0.01', currency: 'EUR' }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                });
            },
            // onAuthorize() is called when the buyer approves the payment
            onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {

                // Make a call to the REST api to execute the payment
                return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
                    window.alert('Payment Complete!');
                });
            }
        }, '#paypal-button-container');
    </script>
```